Рекурсия и указатели внутри класса, дерево, C++
Решаю задачу: запрограммировать генерацию арифметического выражения, его вычисление и вывод на экран в виде строки с помощью рекурсии и указателей. Возникла следующая проблема: по какой-то причине арифметические операции и значения, которые находятся на одной глубине, имеют один и тот же адрес. Например, одна из вариаций: на одном узле сами LEFT node и RIGHT node имеют разные адреса, однако int* V в них обоих содержит одинаковый адрес.
Вот код:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class NODE {
private:
    char* OP;
    int* V;
    NODE* LEFT;
    NODE* RIGHT;
public:
    NODE(): OP(nullptr), V(nullptr), LEFT(nullptr), RIGHT(nullptr)
    {}
    NODE(char* temp):
        OP(temp), V(nullptr), LEFT(nullptr), RIGHT(nullptr)
    {}
    NODE(int* temp):
        V(temp), OP(nullptr), LEFT(nullptr), RIGHT(nullptr)
    {}
    int calc() {
        if (V != nullptr) {
            return *V;
        }
        else {
            if (OP != nullptr) {
                switch (*OP) {
                case '+': return LEFT->calc() + RIGHT->calc(); break;
                case '-': return LEFT->calc() - RIGHT->calc(); break;
                case '*': return LEFT->calc() * RIGHT->calc(); break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static NODE* generate(int min, int max, int depth) { 
        if (depth <= 0 || rand() % 3 == 0) {
            int value = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
            return new NODE(&value);
        }
        else {
            char op;
            switch (rand() % 3) {
                case 0: op = '+'; break;
                case 1: op = '-'; break;
                case 2: op = '*'; break;
            }
            NODE* node = new NODE(&op);
            node->LEFT = generate(min, max, depth - 1);
            node->RIGHT = generate(min, max, depth - 1);
            return node;
        }  
    }
    string toString() {
        if (V != nullptr) {
            return to_string(*V);
        }
        else {

            string left_str = LEFT->toString();
            string right_str = RIGHT->toString();
            return left_str + " " + to_string(*OP) + " " + right_str;
        }
    }
    ~NODE() {
        delete OP;
        delete V;
        delete LEFT;
        delete RIGHT;
    }

};


int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr)); 
    NODE* expr = NODE::generate(0, 9, 3);
    cout << "Result: " << expr->calc() << endl;

    return 0;
}

Вот пример дерева с такой ошибкой. 

В этом коде:
int value = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
return new NODE(&value);

вы берете адрес локальной переменной value, и возвращаете его из функции, в составе нового узла.
Учитывая, что потом (в деструкторе NODE) вы собираетесь вызвать delete для переменной V, получается, что конструктор ожидает указатель на int, созданный через new, а не указатель на локальную переменную:
return new NODE( new int(value) );

